# gulp-nunjucks-render include paths

Tags: gulp, nunjucks, gulp-nunjucks-render

I have a project set up like this:

[image: Gulp project structure]

and I'm using `gulp-nunjucks-render` for templating. My `gulpfile.js` looks like this:

```
gulp.task('nunjucks', function() {
  // Gets .html and .nunjucks files in pages folder
  return gulp.src('pages/**/*.+(html|nunjucks)')
  // Renders template with nunjucks
  .pipe(nunjucksRender({
      path: ['templates']
    }))
  // output file to main folder
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

It works well, and creates an index.html in my root folder.
However, whenever i want to include a partial from `templates/partials/bottomnav.nunjucks`, nothing happens. The index file is created, but the bottomnav html is not included.

I have been following [this guide](https://zellwk.com/blog/nunjucks-with-gulp/) and so my `index.nunjucks` looks like this:

```
<!-- index.nunjucks -->
{% extends "layout.nunjucks" %}

{% block content %}

<h1>This is the index page</h1>
{% include "partials/bottomnav.nunjucks" %}

{% endblock %}
```

-- but why is the partial not included? Is the path wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the setup above actually works.